# CloudKit design advice

Tags: ios, cloudkit

Let me preface by saying I know the pros and cons of using CloudKit and that I am trying to work around one of these issues. However since Cloudkit is more or less free, thats what I'm using. I am aware this might be easier with a different framework.

For simplicity sake lets say I'm making a social media image sharing app, I want to track photo likes and my framework is CloudKit. I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way to track likes for publicly shared photos.

A few of the options I've mulled over:

1. Every like is a new record in the public database with a back reference to the photo. Since CK has no aggregate queries, in order to display the number of likes for a photo I need to query all the records for a given reference and count them. If this number gets very large then I'm iterating over the cursor. This seems quick and accurate to write but potentially pretty slow to display a lot of photos.
2. Likes are individual records in the private database, I update the aggregate in a single record per photo the public db at the same time. Getting the total like count is now a one record query. Determining if a user has already liked something also becomes easier with a smaller private db of likes. The route sounds like the fastest but its is potentially inaccurate if multiple users are liking the same photo. Also deleting a user and all their private likes leaves my aggregates unchanged, I'd need some process updating the aggregates.

I'd love any advice I can get, thanks !

Comment: If you're going to down vote at least say why, anyone can click a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You second approach is the best, and it's accurate. When you read a data, change it and save it, CloudKit will check if the data is changed in the mean time. So when 2 are updating 1 photo at the same time, then one will get a CloudKit error that the data has changed. Then just try to update again until you succeed.

No matter what solution you choose, if you want to update the likes after a user is removed, you need a process that does this.

Comment: This is working out great by the way, forced me to rethink my approach. Doing a lot of rewrite but thats how it goes.

Comment: @rjb101 Did you stick with this solution? Am I right that you had two distinct record types, a photo record type and a separate record type for aggregating the like count (which was based on a third record type for the likes themselves), or did you just aggregate the like count on the photo record itself? It seems avoiding the intermediary aggregate record type would avoid an extra call per photo and enable a single request for photos to provide all the desired data immediately, though it could create more collisions on updating photos, since there could also be comment updates etc. happening.

Comment: Come to think of it, both my scenarios seem to be slightly off from what you described. Could you explain why the likes are in a private database in your second scenario (the one you went with) and not public? I don't see how that detail affects the question of how the likes are aggregated.